# my log in form logic seems flawed and i cant figure it out

Tags: vb.net, authentication

Im making a log in form where users can input their details to get to the main program, and (eventually) the users will be able to change their passwords

My "Passwords.txt" file contains:

```
123
Password
```

And this is the code that executes to see whether their username and password are correct or not

```
Imports System.IO
    Public Class LogIn
        Public Structure info
            Dim Username As String
            Dim Password As String
        End Structure

        Dim details As info

        Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

            If txtUsername.Text = details.Password And txtPassword.Text = details.Password Then
                Form1.Show()
                Me.Hide()
            Else
                MsgBox("Your Username or Password is incorrect!")
                txtPassword.Text = ""
                txtUsername.Text = ""

            End If

        End Sub

        Private Sub LogIn_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            Dim FILE = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("Passwords.txt")
            Dim myArray As String() = FILE
            details.Username = myArray(0)
            details.Password = myArray(1)
        End Sub
    End Class
```

No matter what i put into txtUsername and txtPassword it always shows the message box

Comment: Change this `If txtUsername.Text = details.Password`

Comment: Tell me that this is just for debugging. You wouldn´t store user passwords without encryption in a text file would you?

Comment: This is only a school project so no need to hash, etc. Only trying to fulfill a small criteria :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're checking txtUsername against details.Password instead of details.Username. :)